# Create spreadsheet with Google Sheets API V4 API Key

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, google-sheets-api

I've figured out how to read values from a Budgeting Spreadsheet I created, but I can't figure out how to create a new spreadsheet with the Sheets API V4. I've been struggling with this problem for 5 months by now, has anyone solved this problem before?

Here's my code:

```
// READ - WORKING!
router.get("/get", (req, res) => {
  var id = '1LoSF_4Z9aoiVvDsjFV9CMOd--vvz3fERfOPajVb2sv8';  
  var params = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/?key='
  var url = params + apiKey;
  request(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${id}?key=${apiKey}`, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log("Body", body);
  });
})

// Create - NOT WORKING!
router.post('/create', (req,res)=>{
  request({
    method: 'POST',
    uri: `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets?fields=properties%2Ftitle&key=${apiKey}`
  }, (error, response, body)=>{

    console.log(body);
    //Logs the body of the newly created spreadsheet

  })
})
```

I used the guidelines from Google's API Explorer, you can find it here:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.create

Thank you!

Comment: The create method of Sheets API cannot be used by the API key. So how about using OAuth2 and service account?

Comment: Thank you! So that is great to know. I do have OAuth2 setup in another application which authorizes the scopes of Google Sheets. How do I do a POST request that passes the OAuth access token to the sheets api and creates a spreadsheet? Do you have an example of how to do this? I understand the concept but I've never seen it being used.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about your situation? You have already retrieved the access token from OAuth2 process. And you can use the access token. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I have the access token returned from Google after I've authenticated with OAuth. With that token I can now post to create a spreadsheet in my own drive, or whoever is logged in. Do you have any other questions?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted the modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? In this modified script, the access token you retrieved is used. When you create Spreadsheet using Sheets API, please include ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`` to the scopes. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Add `headers` using the access token.
- Add `body` for giving the title of created spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

```
request({
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets?fields=properties%2Ftitle%2CspreadsheetId',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({properties: {title: "sampleTitle"}}),
}, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(body);
});
```

#### Note:

- When you use this script, please use the access token including `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` to the scopes. This scope is used to create the spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)

Comment: Probably best to also request the `spreadsheetId` of the created Google Sheets file so it can be worked with immediately (instead of just the `title` field)

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your comment. I followed the user's query parameters. But also I think that your comment will be useful for user's situation. So I updated the script.

Comment: Got it! Thank you.

Comment: Hello! how can I manage it with API Key? I dont want to refresh token all the time...

Comment: @M. Mariscal Unfortunately, the create method of Sheets API cannot be used by the API key. I deeply apologize for this current specification.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it to work! Similar to the previous response (thank you Tanaike!!!).

```
request({
method: 'POST',
url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets',
headers:{
  'Authorization': 'Bearer (access token goes here)'
},
body: JSON.stringify({
  properties: {
    title: "Spreadsheet Title Goes Here"
  }
})}, (error, response, body)=>{
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
      var info = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(info);
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  })
```

Comment: I'm glad your issue was solved. But I'm sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: If I'd seen your response I would've solved it because they're pretty much the same. You did solve it, thank you!

Comment: Thanks. If your issue was resolved, please accept it as the resolved question. It will be useful for users who have the same issue.

Comment: Hi Can you please tell how you are getting the access token ?